# Реализации синхронизации между сервером и клиентом

Tags: android, база-данных, django, клиент-сервер, synchronized

Есть проект клиент(android)-сервер. На клиенте есть своя локальная база данных, также предусмотрено общение с сервером. Ведущее устройство получается клиент. Так как часто происходят действия которые нужно добавить в локальную базу и синхронизировать с сервером.
Как правильно организовать логистику по синхронизации данных с сервером?
выбрал пока такой путь:

**У каждой записи есть метка времени последнего изменения. Unixtime вполне сойдет. Это поле ставит только сервер. Когда вы создаете на телефоне новую запись или редактируете пришедшую с сервера - ставите в метку 0. При синхронизации телефон отправляет на сервер список записей, у которых время 0(все измененные и созданные данные) и время последней синхронизации(0 по умолчанию). Сервер кушает данные, записывает изменения, и отдает текущее свое время(которое сохраняется на телефоне как время последней синхронизации) и все данные, время изменения которых больше присланного телефоном времени последней синхронизации.**

Но встал в тупик, так как получается что id сервера на каждую запись, и id клиента различаются.

Придумал вариант с хранением на сервере поля deviceID, который хранит индекс с клиента.
Но мне кажется что я не совсем правильно действую, так как теряю цепочку индексов сервера.

Подскажите пожалуйста какие варианты синхронизации можно придумать?
Либо сценарий синхронизации клиент-сервер при первом запуске приложения.

Comment: Как минимум нужен ClientID а не DeviceID - пользователь может зайти с 10 разных устройств. При создании записи поле ID принимает нулевое значение, при передаче сервер отдает ID. При обновлении взводится поле Update и запись обновляется на сервере при соединении (зачем время?). ИМХО.

Comment: @Style-7 какой ID принимает нулевое значение? А если в данный момент нет сети?

Comment: Локальная база данных, когда нет сети а пользователь вводит данные. При появлении соединения те записи у которых нет ID передаются на сервер а он возвращает значение.

Comment: @Style-7 вы имеете ввиду server_id или id который primary key?

Comment: server_id .....